# Material-UI: Autocmplete: How to use regular input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How is it possible to use a regular `input` instead of a `TextField` in a `Autocomplete`?

I thought it works like this but it doesn't. :(

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-f4ofp

Comment: you must control your inputs in react, you cannot let the browser control them

Comment: @JoeLloyd maybe you could adjust my code? 

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use something like:

```html
<label for="movie">Choose a Movie:</label>
<input list="movieList" id="movie" name="movie-list" />

<datalist id="movieList">
    <option value="The Shawshank Redemption">
    <option value="The Godfather">
    <option value="Schindler's List">
    <option value="Pulp Fiction">
    <option value="Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back">
    <option value="Inception">
    <option value="Goodfellas">
    <option value="The Matrix">
    <option value="City of God">
    <option value="Requiem for a Dream">
    <option value="Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind">
    <option value="Dangal">
    <option value="Like Stars on Earth">
    <option value="A Clockwork Orange">
    <option value="Braveheart">
    <option value="Oldboy">
    <option value="Witness for the Prosecution">
    <option value="Singin' in the Rain">
    <option value="Inglourious Basterds">
</datalist>
```

Comment: This is not an option because every browser renders different and/or has a different behavior (look at firefox, you have to double click in the input to see the options).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the **whole** API documentation (also the corresponding Components) is the key: Just use a standard `TextField` and disable the underline from the `Input`: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xhzsw